# How to prevent stupid websites from breaking the "scroll wheel mode"?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, scrolling, web, vivaldi

The only website from which I can order groceries is doing something incredibly annoying. Example: https://www.mat.se/search.html

Somehow, they have managed (deliberately or through incompetence) to break the "scroll wheel mode" which I constantly use. To be clear, I'm not talking about simply using the scroll wheel to scroll up and down directly. I'm talking about where you middle-click (with the wheel button on the mouse) on the page and then start moving the cursor up and down to scroll, which I've been doing for decades and which feels extremely natural to me.

I don't even understand how it's technically possible for a website to interfere with this feature of the Web browser, but clearly, it's possible.

I thought this would stop happening when I finally stopped using Pale Moon and switched to the closest thing I'll ever come to Google Chrome: Vivaldi. But it happens there just like in Pale Moon. Very annoying.

Can somebody explain to me:

1. How is this possible on a technical level?
2. How can I force this feature back for the webpages that do whatever they are doing to break it?

Comment: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930875/disabling-middle-click-scrolling-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

> How is this possible on a technical level?

Likely JavaScript. JavaScript can be used to determine what does (or doesn't) happen when you click something in a web page.

> How can I force this feature back for the webpages that do whatever they are doing to break it?

You will probably need a browser extension that can modify the web page (via so-called "userscripts"), such as:

- Greasemonkey (Firefox)
- Tampermonkey (Chrome)
- Violentmonkey (Firefox and Chrome)

The hardest part about this would be determining the elements to remove. Repositories of userscripts exist. But if a userscript for your site doesn't exist, you may be stuck trying to write your own.